# How do I mix between addClass Api and fadein?

Tags: javascript, css, fadein, addclass

I just would like to put color on div by `addClass` event and then it should fade in.

```
$("#box1").hover(
    function () {
        $("#box2").addClass("blue");
        $("#box3").addClass("yellow");
    },
    function () {
        $("#box2").removeClass("blue");
        $("#box3").removeClass("yellow");
    }
);

$("#box2").hover(
    function () {
        $("#box1").addClass("blue");
        $("#box4").addClass("yellow");
    },
    function () {
        $("#box1").removeClass("blue");
        $("#box4").removeClass("yellow");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's pretty ugly but it's worked :

```
$('#box1').hover(function () {
  $("#box2").fadeOut(0).addClass('blue').fadeIn(300);
},
function () {
  $("#box2").fadeOut(300).queue(function(){ $(this).removeClass('blue').fadeIn(0).dequeue()});
});
```

Demo here : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tfe4L/)